# Netsuite using Bearer token getting error 401: Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, netsuite, bearer-token, http-status-code-401

Getting a error 401: Authorization has been denied for this request. Trying to do a request to an external application. Using Bearer token OAuth2, works fine in Postman but when using Javascript in a client SuiteScript produces the 401 error. Have checked so many things in the header, but nothing seems to work in Javascript. Any suggestions? My code below.

```
    this.sendHttpPost = function (actionType) {

        var _response = EMPTY_STRING;
        try {
            var input = JSON.stringify(this._saveDocumentAction);
            jQuery.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: this._url + actionType,
                cache: false,
                data: input.toString(),
                crossDomain: true,
                type: "POST",
                //beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                //    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this._token +'');
                //},
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this._token,
                accept: 'application/json', 
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: false
            }).done(function (data) {
                _response = data;
                }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    alert(textStatus + " " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseJSON.Message);
            });


        } catch (e){
            log.error({
                title: "Error: ",
                details: e.message
                
            });
        }
        return _response;

    }
```